# Identify keyword in active record query-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
@zipcode = ZipCodes.identify(params[:zip_code])
```

I am new to rails. Can anyone tell me what does the keyword 'identify' do. Is this related to active record query?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet/identify/class

Comment: @Salil: why do you think it's this particular `identify`? (hint: it's not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gem *zip-codes* provides the `ZipCodes` class with a `identify` class method that simply reads a zip code and returns the state, city and timezone.

```
ZipCodes.identify('30301')
# => {:state_code=>"GA", :state_name=>"Georgia", :city=>"Atlanta", :time_zone=>"America/New_York"}
```

How do I/you know this? I guess you are new to the project where you saw this line:

1. First look inside your project? Do you have a class called *ZipCodes*? Yes, look in there.
2. No, look into your *Gemfile*, do you have anything mentioning `ZipCodes` or similar? Yes, search for the gem documentation.
3. No, Google a code snippet `ZipCodes.identify` and search among the results.

Here is the documentation for *zip-codes*: https://github.com/monterail/zip-codes